# Ember s of project giving error: Cannot find module './lib/md5-hex' in ember js.

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, npm

I specifically tried the following

> npm uninstall md5-hex --save
>
> npm install md5-hex --save

and then did ember s. It didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Searched for ./lib/md5-hex throughout the project and replaced it with 'md5-hex'. It fixed that particular error.